# What would cause Code128 barcodes generated from the netbarcodewriter library not to scan?

Tags: c#, barcode, code128

I'm trying to use the netbarcodewriter from https://github.com/simongh/barcodes to generate code128 barcodes. The barcode generated can only be scanned by some smartphone apps, but not from any USB scanners or ruggedized windows mobile 6 scanners we have.

For example the attached images show "502337700000000198" encoded from different sources, only 1 (ios) smartphone app - Zbarcode can scan the barcode generated by netbarcodewriter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRInr.png), others (attscanner) can't. None of the usb scanners or ruggedised windows ce terminals scan it either.

[image: from netbarcodewriter]

[image: from raco]

[image: from itextsharp]

```
string huid = "502337700000000198";

short w = 251;
short h = 100;
short x = 28;
Code128 code = new Code128();

var b2mp = code.Generate(huid, new BarcodeSettings { BarHeight = 65, WideWidth = w - 2 * x });
b2mp.Save(string.Format(@"c:\temp\{0}.png", huid), ImageFormat.Png);
```

When generated by itextsharp [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD2wN.png) or on sites like racoindustries.com/barcodegenerator/1d/code-128.aspx [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwfLN.gif), all the scanners work. iTextSharp's barcode is just too small, and the BarcodeSize property can't be set.

Has any one worked with this library? Also, does anyone know what those #MARKER grey rectangles do?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the #marker grey rectangles are a debug feature to allow you to read the barcode by eye easier. They shouldn't be used in production

Comment: A quick look by eye & looks like the widths are off slightly in the top image. I'll see if I can figure out why

Comment: Thanks. I used an image editing tool to "make them fit" and I noticed that every third space was too wide. Just every third space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a sort of bug. When you create a new Code128 class, it sets it's default settings. for Code 128, this means setting module padding - the space between an encoded number - to 0.

In the code you've got above, you pass in a new settings object. This sets the padding back to it's default of 2, hence the extra spacing.

You're also setting the `WideWidth`. This isn't used in Code128 - it only uses `NarrowWidth` These are the width of the bars & default to 2.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed that and it works on all the scanners.